# Open CV Assertion Failed error

Tags: c++, opencv, raspberry-pi, ros

I am currently getting this error:

### Error

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size()) in getMat_, file 

/tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 1200

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'

what():  /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-opencv3-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:1200:

error: (-215) 0 <= i && i < (int)vv.size() in function getMat_
```

### Code

I am currently working on this code, trying to find circles in a video feed I am acquiring from a robot. After some clever commenting, I discovered that whenever **Hough Circles** (`cv::HoughCircles`) does detect a circle, I get the error as indicated above.

```
cv::Size strel_size;
strel_size.width = 3; 
strel_size.height = 3; 
cv::Mat strel = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, 
                    strel_size);
cv::morphologyEx(img_bin, intr_ptr, cv::MORPH_OPEN, strel,
        cv::Point(-1,-1), 3);

//cv::medianBlur(intr_ptr, copy_ptr, 7);
cv::bitwise_not(intr_ptr,intr_ptr);
cv::GaussianBlur(intr_ptr, intr_ptr, cv::Size(7,7), 2, 2);
cv::vector< cv::vector<int> > circles;
cv::HoughCircles(intr_ptr, circles, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 70, 140, 15, 20, 
                    400);

for(size_t i = 0; i < circles.size(); i++) {
    cv::Point center(cvRound(circles[i][0]), cvRound(circles[i][1]));
    int radius = cvRound(circles[i][2]);
    cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, center, 3, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), -1, 8, 0);
    cv::circle(cv_ptr->image, center, radius + 1, cv::Scalar(0,255,0), 
               2, 8, 0);
    ROS_INFO("x: %d, y: %d, r: %d\n", center.x, center.y, radius);
}

//cv::imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW1, cv_ptr->image);
cv::imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW2, cv_ptr->image);
//cv::imshow(OPENCV_WINDOW3, copy_ptr->image);

cv::waitKey(3);
```

### Background

I am currently trying to build an autonomous drone using *ROS* on my *Rapsberry Pi* which is running an *Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS*. Solving the Computer Vision problem of recognizing red circles as of now.

Comment: Index is out of bounds somewhere. According to the debugger, which of the statements in above code does this exception come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens because the output array for the circles doesn't have the correct format. The [cv::HoughCircles](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) function takes a cv::vector, not a vector of vectors as type for the circle array. Also the values are float, not integer.

Compare the tutorial at http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d70/tutorial_hough_circle.html

(What happens is that when cv::HoughCircles finds a circle, it attempts to access the vec3f matrix - however in your case this is an (empty) cv::vector of integers and hence the size-assertion fails.)

Comment: Using `<Vec3f>` leads me to the error `'Vec3f' was not declared in this scope`

Comment: Should I be using `Vec3b`?

Comment: So I think I understand what the problem is. Since vectors do not exist in the new OpenCV and it just uses the `std::vector class` and as it shown [here](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.10/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#vec),  we need to declare this as `cv::Vec3f`, in case of software where the OpenCV is being bridged. However, this is the correct answer and thanks!

Comment: I still gett OpenCV Error: Assertion failed  even with that code:    cv::Vec3f circ;    cv::Mat blured;     cv::HoughCircles( blured, circ, CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, 20, 50, 30, 0, 0 );
 any ideas?

Comment: @sqp_125 try `cv::vector<cv::Vec3f> circ` - check the tutorial I linked.