# How to find the colored circles in an image opencv python for game development

Tags: python, opencv

I have an image of an layout I'm tyring to find out the somewhat coloured circles
this piece of code is not able to identify the circles

This is the image I need to identify the circles of different colors

[image]

Code:-

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('test7.png',0)
img = cv2.equalizeHist(img)
cimg = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=25)

circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
for i in circles[0,:]:
    # draw the outer circle
    cv2.circle(cimg,(i[0],i[1]),i[2],(0,255,0),2)

cv2.imshow('detected circles',cimg)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

But this is giving me error 
Error

```
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(img,cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT,1,10,param1=50,param2=30,minRadius=0,maxRadius=25)
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/hough.cpp:1737: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_image.empty() && _image.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) && (_image.isMat() || _image.isUMat()) in function 'HoughCircles'
```

I have 3 images Dog, Monkey, Donkey.

I need to place these images of dog, monkey, donkey on those circles and resize them.

Pics of those images

[image]

[image]

[image]

I want the final output like this.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41950778/7919597

or 

http://answers.opencv.org/question/11812/why-am-i-getting-this-opencv-error-assertion-failed/

Comment: My code is not detecting the circle I guess its passing the None instead

Comment: @HowardGENG Thanks Im just learning openCV for my game development

Comment: Yes I need to draw the circles myself first

Comment: Does it mean you already know the coordinates of every circle's  center?  Or you have to locate the circles using image processing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177261/discussion-between-howard-geng-and-user9538877).

Comment: Do you have a pictutre without the circles? If so, you can just subtract that from the image with the circles and find the differences very simply.

Comment: Yeah I get it.. @MarkSetchell is it possible to just paste the pics of dog,monkey,donkey in a new photo with white background ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try by filtering out your circles by transforming the image into HSV color space - `cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV`. Then you can search your for your colors with `cv2.inRange()` and draw them on a mask (different mask for every color)

Something like this:

[image]

[image]

[image]

After you have the circles filtered out, you can search for contours with `cv2.findContours()` and find its position (you can search for it's center point or its extreme points) to determen where on the image you should put your smaller images. Note that I have resised your smaller images manually and if you whould want to have different sizes of the same picture you will have to modify the code. Also if you would like to keep transparency you should play with the chanells of your images and change the code. This is just an example on how I would approach the task.

Example code (without transparency and with same size pictures):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('thermal2.png')
dog = cv2.imread('resize1.jpg')
donkey = cv2.imread('resize2.jpg')
monkey = cv2.imread('resize3.png')

resize1 = cv2.resize(dog, (35, 40))
resize2 = cv2.resize(donkey, (60, 35))
resize3 = cv2.resize(monkey, (40, 40))

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

lower_blue = np.array([110,50,50])
upper_blue = np.array([130,255,255])
lower_red = np.array([0,50,50])
upper_red = np.array([10,255,255])
lower_yellow = np.array([30,50,50])
upper_yellow = np.array([50,255,255])

mask_blue = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_blue, upper_blue)
mask_red = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_red, upper_red)
mask_yellow = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_yellow, upper_yellow)

res_blue = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask_blue)
res_red = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask_red)
res_yellow = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask=mask_yellow)

gray_blue = cv2.cvtColor(res_blue, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_red = cv2.cvtColor(res_red, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray_yellow = cv2.cvtColor(res_yellow, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

_,thresh_blue = cv2.threshold(gray_blue,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_,thresh_red = cv2.threshold(gray_red,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_,thresh_yellow = cv2.threshold(gray_yellow,10,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

_, contours_blue, hierarhy1 = cv2.findContours(thresh_blue,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_, contours_red, hierarhy2 = cv2.findContours(thresh_red,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_, contours_yellow, hierarhy3 = cv2.findContours(thresh_yellow,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for c in contours_red:
    size = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if size > 30:
        cXY_left = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        cXY_top = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        cX = cXY_left[0]
        cY = cXY_top[1]
        img[cY:cY+resize1.shape[0], cX:cX+resize1.shape[1]]=resize1

for c in contours_blue:
    size = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if size > 30:
        cXY_left = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        cXY_top = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        cX = cXY_left[0]
        cY = cXY_top[1]
        img[cY:cY+resize2.shape[0], cX:cX+resize2.shape[1]]=resize2

for c in contours_yellow:
    size = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if size > 30:
        cXY_left = tuple(c[c[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
        cXY_top = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
        cX = cXY_left[0]
        cY = cXY_top[1]
        img[cY:cY+resize3.shape[0], cX:cX+resize3.shape[1]]=resize3

cv2.imshow('blue', res_blue)
cv2.imshow('red', res_red)
cv2.imshow('yellow', res_yellow)
cv2.imshow('img',img)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Hi thank you!! In the end output is it possible to make the background as completely white with just images of monkey,donkey,dog ?

Comment: It is posible but as I mentioned in the answer you have to play around with channels of your pictures. As far as I know .png has 4 channels and .jpg has 3 channels so you would probably have to add another channel or something like that - I do not have much experience in this. To make the circles white add 'cv2.drawContours(img, [c], -1, (255,255,255), -1)' to for loops.

Comment: I'm sorry do you mean a blank (white) mask with only the pictures of animals or do you mean only pictures of animals with transparent background on the original image? You have to understand that you uploaded pictures in .jpg format and the transparency is lost when converting from .png to .jpg.