# How to fetch x,y coordinates of specific pixels(blue colored) from an image in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing, coordinates, image-segmentation

My task is to get the x,y coordinates from the segmented image(blue dots) as produced by the code. How do I automate this process? My end results should be a zip of x,y coordinates of these blue dots as produced in the second image.
[image]

Code to generate the blue points:

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import cv2_imshow
# from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
 
    image = cv2.imread('./S3/frame35.jpg')
#cv2_imshow(image)

    result = image.copy()
 
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # lower boundary RED color range values; Hue (0 - 10)
    lower1 = np.array([0, 100, 20])
    upper1 = np.array([10, 255, 255])

    # upper boundary RED color range values; Hue (160 - 180)
    lower2 = np.array([160,100,20])
    upper2 = np.array([179,255,255])

    lower_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower1, upper1)
    upper_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower2, upper2)

    full_mask = lower_mask + upper_mask;

    result = cv2.bitwise_and(result, result, mask=full_mask)

    plt.figure(figsize=[20,20])
    plt.axis("off")
#     plt.subplot(121);plt.imshow(image[:,:,::-1]);plt.title("Original Image",fontdict={'fontsize': 25});plt.axis('off');
    plt.subplot(122);plt.imshow(result, cmap='gray');plt.title("Mask of red Color",fontdict={'fontsize': 25});plt.axis('on');
    plt.savefig('mask_1.jpg', bbox_inches = 'tight')
#     cv2_imshow(full_mask)
#     cv2_imshow(result)
    #print(full_mask)
    #print(result) 
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: This question has already been answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51646047/how-to-find-the-colored-circles-in-an-image-opencv-python-for-game-development/51649268#51649268

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather straightforward to do by computing the connected components of a binary image.

First you'd have to threshold your image to get a binary image that segments the dots. You can do this for instance with `cv2.threshold`.
Then you can use `cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats`, this will - among other things - return a list of the centroids for all the components. One of them will be the background though, but among the returned values there is an integer arrray of the same size where all components have a different label. So you can look up the label of the component of the background and remove that from the centroid coordinates.

---

EDIT: The code you added does not even run, but I feed it your second screenshot as a `mask.png` and use the mentioned commands as follows, and the plot the `centroids` over the image:

```
src = cv2.imread('mask.png')
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(src[:, :, 0:1], 120, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, _, _, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
```

[image]

---

EDIT2: Appending following snipped to your newest version results in this:

[image]

```
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(result[:, :, 0:1], 20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
_, _, _, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
plt.imshow(thresh)
plt.plot(centroids[:,0], centroids[:, 1], 'or', mfc='none')
plt.show()
```

Comment: @AMANDEEPKAUR The code you posted doesn't seem to run. And it would be nice to have the original image that your code is applied to, not just a screenshot.

Comment: No, the issue is not with the upside-down coordinate as the ground truth is based on this scaling. I am not able to get the right coordinates even after trying your code. Is it because of the image size difference? I have uploaded the original image and the code for mask, could you please try if it works at your end? Help would be appreciated as I am stuck on this problem statement from days!

Comment: I updated my answer again to show you what it looks like.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works correctly now!

Comment: Just a minor doubt, in first image, we see discreet circles and detection points, in the newest version, we see they form clusters, I change the value of 20 -> 100 which seems okish but still it shows clusters in contours, what could be the reason for this?

Comment: This is because you got disjoint clusters of pixels with that threshold - in the first pictuer they were not present because used a way smaller resolution (your screenshot). If you want that I recommend applying a smoothing (low pass) filter before thresholding , or maybe a morphological closing operation after the thresholding.

Comment: Thanks Applied median filter and the results are accurate!

Answer (score 0):

The final code with all the above-suggested changes has been implemented below. Using the median filter before the threshold, I am able to limit the number of contours detected. Next I am able to access the specific x,y coordinates by using the index values.

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# import cv2_imshow
# from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
 
    image = cv2.imread('./S3/frame35.jpg')
#cv2_imshow(image)

    result = image.copy()
 
    image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    # lower boundary RED color range values; Hue (0 - 10)
    lower1 = np.array([0, 100, 20])
    upper1 = np.array([10, 255, 255])

    # upper boundary RED color range values; Hue (160 - 180)
    lower2 = np.array([160,100,20])
    upper2 = np.array([179,255,255])

    lower_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower1, upper1)
    upper_mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower2, upper2)

    full_mask = lower_mask + upper_mask;

    result = cv2.bitwise_and(result, result, mask=full_mask)

    plt.figure(figsize=[20,20])
    plt.axis("off")
#     plt.subplot(121);plt.imshow(image[:,:,::-1]);plt.title("Original Image",fontdict={'fontsize': 25});plt.axis('off');
    plt.subplot(122);plt.imshow(result, cmap='gray');plt.title("Mask of red Color",fontdict={'fontsize': 25});plt.axis('on');
#     plt.savefig('mask_1.jpg', bbox_inches = 'tight')

    median = cv2.medianBlur(result,9)
    _, thresh = cv2.threshold(median[:, :, 0:1],20, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    _, _, _, centroids = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(thresh, 8, cv2.CV_32S)
    plt.imshow(thresh)
   
    plt.plot(centroids[:,0], centroids[:, 1], 'or', mfc='none')
    plt.show()

    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).